# Django: Edit related models - Reverse way with custom forms

Tags: django, forms

I've just started my first django app, after going through the tutorial and several small samples. I've the following models (very simplified):

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Vacancy(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    candidates = models.ManyToManyField(Candidate, blank=True, null=True)
```

I've created a form where I can add a new Vacancy, and the candidates are shown as a multi-choose box:

```
class CandidateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate

class VacancyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vacancy
```

But, how should I add a choose box on the Candidate form, so I can also check which vacancies a Candidate is applying?

I've found inline forms, but can not realize how to use them by reading the doc.

Thanks a lot in advance.

BR,
Ignacio.

Answer (score 0):

Manually adding a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) should get you halfway there:

```
from django import forms

class CandidateForm(ModelForm):
    vacancies = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Vacancy.objects.order_by("title"))
    class Meta:
        model = Candidate
```

Then in your view, you would do something like:

```
if request.POST:
    form = CandidateForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        candidate = form.save()
        for v in form.cleaned_data["vacancies"]:
            v.candidates.add(candidate)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Tom!! Then inline forms and form sets have nothing to do with this issue? Your answer seems pretty easy, thanks again!

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the admin? That's the only place where inline forms would really come into it. You could definitely do it with formsets instead of my example, but I think this is simpler.

Comment: One more question, related to what Tom said: I do also have a candidate_edit view, which gets all the fields initialized with the values from the candidate_id that comes in the view call, but I've not been able to pre-select the right values on the MultipleChoiceField...   I tried a   "    form.fields["vacancies"].queryset = candidate.oferta_set.all()
" but that's changing the available values, not selecting the ones that are already on the Candidate... any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I did it with the "form.fields["vacancies"].initial = candidate.oferta_set.all()" line :-)  Btw, is not possible to have rich formatting on comments?

Comment: Check the "help" link on the bottom right of the text box after hitting "Add Comment". It shows what is possible in the comments.